# HtmlEncode List<string> values

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have cell values saved in List like this

```
public List<string> Cell { get; set; }
```

I want do htmlEncode to each value of this list.
can anyone help me with this??

Comment: where is the code where you are Adding to the List or List Cell ..? show appropriate code please..

Answer (score 2):

```
Cell = Cell.Select(s => System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(s)).ToList();
```

or
 shorter:

```
Cell = Cell.Select(System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`ConvertAll<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73fe8cwf.aspx) extension method :

```
Cell = Cell.ConvertAll<string>(s => System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(s));
```

or shorter :

```
Cell = Cell.ConvertAll<string>(System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode);
```

Comment: I think your solution is better than mine.  I did not know about `ConvertAll`.  What about:  `Cell = Cell.ConvertAll(System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode);`.  I would upvote that.

Comment: @PhilipFourie : Thanks, added your short version.

Answer (score 0):

you could create an extension method that does the trick

```
 public static class MyCustomListMethod
    {
        public static void Add(this IList<string> list, string item,bool htmlEndode){
            list.Add(System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(item));
        }
    }
```

and then

```
   public static void Main()
        {
            string e = "<p>Test Text<p/>";
            List<string> mylist = new List<string>();
            mylist.Add(e,true);

        }
```

using the new extension method you will be able to add item to a list already encoded instead of converting all of them